# Service variable from component shows empty in Angular 10

Tags: angular

Service Variable is showing empty when calling from particular component.

I have initialized Service variable from app initializer like this:

```
export function initializeApp(appInitService: AppInitService) {
  return (): Promise<any> => { 
    return appInitService.Init();
  }
}

{ provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initializeApp, deps: [AppInitService], multi: true},
```

app-init.service.ts

```
import { Injectable }  from '@angular/core';
import { PubService } from './pub.global.service';
 
@Injectable()
export class AppInitService {
    constructor(private pubService: PubService) {
    }
    Init() {
        return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
            this.pubService.GetStoreData();
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve();
            }, 6000);
        });
    }
}
```

pub.global.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CustomUrlBaseService } from './auth/customurlbase';
import { Observable, Subject, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Resolve } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class PubService extends CustomUrlBaseService implements Resolve<any> {
    appRoot = '/api/pub';
    StoreData = {};
    private loadPub = new BehaviorSubject<any>(this.StoreData);
    loadPubObservable$ = this.loadPub.asObservable();
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
      super();
    }
    resolve() {
      // this.GetStoreData();
    }
    GetStoreData() {
      this.GetData().subscribe(res => {
        this.StoreData = res;
        this.loadPub.next(this.StoreData);
        console.log(this.StoreData);
      })
    }
   GetData(): Observable<any> {
    const url = (`${this.baseURL + this.appRoot}/GetStoreData`);
    return this.http.get(url);
  }
  publishChange(log: string) {
    this.GetStoreData();
  }
}
```

trying to access StoreData variable from component:

```
this.storeData = this.pubService.StoreData;
```

Now this.storeData is showing empty object {}

However, if I check this from other component say; my layout component like Header, Footer or layout component. It works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object is not available because the common service is not injected into the component and so the same object is not availabe, every time you go to this component a new object is getting initialized

Solution is -

The reason this happens is that the component might not have the root injectable
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })

Once you provide this in the component, what happens is that this will be injected at root level and will be available throughout the application as single object rather than creating multiple object.

If this is not given then every component will be provided with its own object and the variables will not be passed on.

Comment: I thought about it and this could be the reason, this service is under shared module and imported in that and shared module is further imported in root module. So, I hope there should be no problem.

Comment: I tried to remove PubService from Shared module and put in AppModule but the result is the same.

Comment: Your answer is correct, can you just edit your answer to be in detailed for the other people? I added @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
}) to my service and called it from root module and it worked for me.